# Using Plancherels formula and Fourier-transform table to solve $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-|t|}\frac{\sin t}{t}dt$

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

I would like to solve

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-|t|}\frac{\sin t}{t}dt$

and I tried using Plancherels formula:

\begin{equation}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)g(t)dt=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}(\omega)\hat{g}(\omega)d\omega
\end{equation}

with $f(t)=e^{-|t|}$ and $g(t)=\frac{\sin t}{t}$.

The closest Fourier transforms of these are respectively:

$f(t)\rightarrow e^{-|at|}, \hat{f}(t)=\frac{2a}{a^2+\omega^2}$

$g(t)\rightarrow \frac{sin(\Omega t)}{\pi t}, \hat{g}(t)=\theta(\omega+\Omega)-\theta(\omega-\Omega)$

So what I have here is that $f(t)$ is easily converted to the transform of $f(t)=e^{-|at|}$, giving $\hat{f}(\omega)=\frac{2}{1+\omega^2}$, but for $g(t)$ we are missing a $\pi$ in the denominator, to make $g(t)=\frac{\sin t}{t} \rightarrow \frac{sin(\Omega t)}{\pi t}$.

What can be done here?

I thought of writing:

$f(t)\rightarrow e^{-|at|}, \hat{f}(\omega)=\frac{2a}{a^2+\omega^2}\rightarrow \hat{f}(\omega)=\frac{2}{1+\omega^2}$

$g(t)\rightarrow \frac{sin(\Omega t)}{\pi t}, \hat{g}(t)=\theta(\omega+1)-\theta(\omega-1)$

$g(t)=\frac{\pi\sin t}{\pi t} \rightarrow \hat{g}(t)=\pi(\theta(\omega+1)-\theta(\omega-1))$

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-|t|}\frac{\sin t}{t}dt=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{2}{1+\omega^2}\bigg[\pi(\theta(\omega+1)-\theta(\omega-1))\bigg]d\omega
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-|t|}\frac{\sin t}{t}dt=2\pi \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\theta(\omega+1)}{1+\omega^2}d\omega-2\pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\theta(\omega-1)}{1+\omega^2}d\omega=
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}
f0 \ \ \ \ \ on \ \omega<-1 \\
2\pi^2 \ \ \ \ \ on \ -1 <\omega<1 \\
4\pi^2 \ \ \ \ \ on \ \omega>1 
\end{array}
\end{equation}

But the correct answer is in fact a uniform distribution of the integral, and it results as $\pi/2$.

Comment: Isn't your formula for $\hat f$ missing a constant factor?

Comment: I don't think so, this is all I have in the given exam tables and formulas

Comment: Were you required to use Plancherel's formula and Fourier-transform ?

Comment: Not really, but that is the only familiar methods in the course given, as the integration with $sint=\frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2i}$ gives problems on integration by parts with the $1/t$ term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this finally, by the use of the Plancherel formula in the correct way. It was the integrand that was solved incorrectly. Here is the correct solution, with Plancherels formula

Solve

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-|t|}\frac{\sin t}{t}dt$

We use, as suggested in the original post

Fourier-transform rule:

1. $f(t)\rightarrow e^{-|at|}, \hat{f}(\omega)=\frac{2a}{a^2+\omega^2}$.

Applied on  $f(t)=e^{-|t|}\rightarrow \hat{f}(\omega)=\frac{2}{1+\omega^2}$

2. $g(t)\rightarrow \frac{sin(\Omega t)}{\pi t}, \hat{g}(t)=\theta(\omega+1)-\theta(\omega-1)$

Applied $g(t)=\frac{\pi\sin t}{\pi t} \rightarrow \hat{g}(t)=\pi(\theta(\omega+1)-\theta(\omega-1))$

Using Plancherels formula

\begin{equation}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)g(t)dt=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}(\omega)\hat{g}(\omega)d\omega
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-|t|}\frac{\sin t}{t}dt=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{2}{1+\omega^2}\bigg[\pi(\theta(\omega+1)-\theta(\omega-1))\bigg]d\omega =\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{2\pi}{1+\omega^2} d\omega
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{2\pi}{1+\omega^2} d\omega=\bigg[arctan\omega\bigg]_{-1}^1=\frac{\pi}{2}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2):

*Without Plancherel's formula and Fourier-transform*
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-|t|}\,\frac{\sin (t)}{t}dt=2\int_{0}^\infty e^{-t}\,\frac{\sin (t)}{t}dt=2\, \Im\Bigg[\int_{0}^\infty \,\frac{e^{-(1-i)t}}{t}dt\Bigg]$$ Let $(1-i)t=-x$ to make
$$\int \,\frac{e^{-(1-i)t}}{t}dt=\int \,\frac{e^x}{x}dx=\text{Ei}(x)$$ Back to $t$
$$\int \,\frac{e^{-(1-i)t}}{t}dt=\text{Ei}(-(1-i) t)$$
$$2\int e^{-t}\,\frac{\sin (t)}{t}dt=i \Big[\text{Ei}(-(1+i) t)-\text{Ei}(-(1-i) t)\Big]$$

Using the bounds and simplifying a bunch of  logarithms with complex arguments
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-|t|}\,\frac{\sin (t)}{t}dt=2\pi -\frac 3 2 \pi=\frac \pi 2$$

Making the problem more general and just doing the same,
$$\int_{0}^\infty  e^{-a t}\,\frac{ \sin (b t)}{t}\,dt=\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right) \quad \text{if} \quad |\Im(b)|\leq \Re(a)\land \Re(a)>0$$